# При запросе JSON через IFrame в IE выдается предложение скачать файл !   Как обойти ?

Tags: 1с, json, javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

Написал кросс-доменный, как показалось на первый взгляд, "Ajax":

```
function MyAjax (url, param, callback, getXml) {
    if (!document.createElement) return;
    var frame = myAjaxCreateIFrame();
    var getIFrameXML = getIFrameXML;
    frame.onSendComplete = function() {callback(getIFrameXML(frame, !getXml));};
    if (param) {
        var isOne = true;
        for (var attr in param) {
            url += (isOne ? "?" : "&") + attr + "=" + param[attr];
            isOne = false;
        };
    };
    frame.src = url;
}

function myAjaxCreateIFrame () {
    var id = 'if' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "<iframe style=\"display:none\" src=\"about:blank\" id=\""+id+"\" name=\""+id+"\" onload=\"sendComplete('"+id+"')\"></iframe>";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function sendComplete (id) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    if (iframe.onSendComplete && typeof(iframe.onSendComplete) == 'function') 
        iframe.onSendComplete();
}

function getIFrameXML (iframe, getText) {
    var doc=iframe.contentDocument;
    if (!doc && iframe.contentWindow) doc=iframe.contentWindow.document;
    if (!doc) doc=window.frames[iframe.id].document;
    if (!doc) return null;
    if (doc.location=="about:blank") return null;
    if (doc.XMLDocument) doc=doc.XMLDocument;
    return getText ? doc.body.innerText : doc;
}
```

В Chrome работает, хотя и выбрасывает ошибку:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:
```

А в IE вообще предлагает скачать файл!

Как убрать эту ошибку и заставить не считать приходящие от сервера данные в IE файлом, а просто открывать их в IFreme?

PS Такие выкрутасы предприняты из-за того что Ajax (даже через proxy) не работает для JSON в тонком клиенте 1C. Кто сталкивался и решил - помогите...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер должен передать тип контента, иначе IE считает что передается поток данных и предлагает его сохранить как файл так как ни JS, ни Flash его не запрашивали...

Comment: Спасибо, я уже решил отказаться от подобных запросов - перешел на ***proxy.cgi***